Issue with positioning a VBA-generated chart below a table in a Word document
I'm encountering an issue while generating a chart from a VBA macro in Microsoft Word. I have a macro that generates a histogram from data in a specific table in my Word document( Table n°12 ). My goal is to position this chart just below this table 12 from which the data is extracted.
I've tried using the Top property to set the vertical position of the chart, but I keep receiving the following error message: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."
Here's the code of my current macro:
Option Explicit

Sub CreateWordChart3()
    Dim oChart As Chart, oTable As Table
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Const START_CELL = "AA1"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Récupérer la table 12 du document
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(12)
    
    ' Ajouter le graphique en tant que forme au document
    Set oShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlColumnClustered)
    
    ' Définir la position du graphique sous la table 12
    With oShape
        .Top = oTable.Range.Tables(1).Rows(oTable.Rows.Count).Range.End(wdParagraph).Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
        .Left = oTable.Range.Left
    End With
    
    ' Obtenir le graphique en tant qu'objet Chart
    Set oChart = oShape.Chart
    
    ' Copier les données de la table dans une feuille Excel temporaire
    oTable.Range.Copy
    Set oSheet = oChart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
    oSheet.Range(START_CELL).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
    ' Créer le tableau 2D
    Call Create2DTable(oSheet, oSheet.Range(START_CELL))
    
    ' Fermer le classeur Excel temporaire
    oChart.ChartData.Workbook.Close
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

I'm seeking advice on how to correctly position the chart below the specified table in my Word document and resolve the error message. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

On which line raise the error?


Conver the chart shape to InlineShape and move to the desired location

Sub CreateWordChart4()
    Dim oChart As Chart, oTable As Table
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oShp As Shape, afterTblRange As Range
    Const START_CELL = "AA1"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)  ' modify as needed
    Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart
    Set oChart = oShp.Chart
    Set oSheet = oChart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
    oTable.Range.Copy
    oSheet.Range(START_CELL).Select
    oSheet.Paste
    Call Create2DTable(oSheet, oSheet.Range(START_CELL))
    oChart.ChartData.Workbook.Close
    
    Set afterTblRange = oTable.Range
    afterTblRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    oShp.ConvertToInlineShape
    oShp.Select
    Selection.Cut
    afterTblRange.Paste
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Wouldn't it be better to start with an inline shape instead of converting? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshapes.addchart2

Definitely it's a good idea. Thanks @TimothyRylatt
